# Aggregate on another aggregation

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataframe like this :

```
user_id  items
1        item1
1        item2
1        item3
2        item1
2        item5
3        item4
3        item2
```

If I put user_id as row and items as columns, I get this :

```
user_id  number_of_items
1        3
2        2
3        2
```

Now I would like to group this result again, like this :

```
number_of_user_id  number_of_items
1                  3
2                  2
```

How can I do this, as a calculated field or in a graph(maybe an histogramm?)

Comment: put CountD(items) on columns

Comment: If I do that, I end up with one single point on my graph

Comment: Not if you also put user_id as a dimension on one of the other (non-filter) shelves. Then you will get a mark for each user_id showing the number of distinct items for each individual user_id.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood your question. My comments above answer a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the following calculated field, called **users_per_item**

```
{ fixed items : countd(user_id) }
```

Then highlight the new measure you just created in the data pane, **users_per_item** and right click to create Bins. Set the bin size to 1 or whatever value you like. That will create a dimension called **users_per_item (bin)**

Finally, you can now use the bin field to create the view you want, say place **users_per_item (bin)** on the columns shelf and CNTD(items) on the rows shelf.

A natural use for LOD calculations for a 2 stage analysis.

Comment: It works, but I don't really understand what it does. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Read about Level of Detail calculations